# SMPlayer mpv crashes when opening multiple files from Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, smplayer

When I select multiple video files from Nemo, SMPlayer can handle them and play one after one.
But I do the same action from Nautilus, MPlayer/mpv has crashed. Here's a sample error log:

```
/usr/bin/mpv --no-config --no-quiet --terminal --no-msg-color --input-ipc-server=/tmp/smplayer-mpv-11d93 --msg-level=ffmpeg/demuxer=error --no-fs --vd-lavc-threads=8 --hwdec=auto --sub-auto=fuzzy --framedrop=decoder+vo --no-input-default-bindings --input-vo-keyboard=no --no-input-cursor --cursor-autohide=no --no-keepaspect --wid=125829140 --monitorpixelaspect=1 --osd-level=0 --osd-fractions --osd-scale=1 --osd-bar-align-y=0.6 --sub-ass --embeddedfonts --sub-ass-line-spacing=0 --sub-scale=1 --sub-font=Arial --sub-color=#ffffffff --sub-shadow-color=#ff000000 --sub-border-color=#ff000000 --sub-border-size=0.75 --sub-shadow-offset=2.5 --sub-font-size=50 --sub-bold=no --sub-italic=no --sub-margin-y=8 --sub-margin-x=20 --sub-codepage=ISO-8859-1 --sub-pos=100 --volume=100 --cache=auto --screenshot-template=cap_%F_%p_%02n --screenshot-format=jpg --screenshot-directory=/home/psw/Pictures/smplayer_screenshots --audio-channels=2 --audio-pitch-correction=yes --volume-max=200 -osd-msg3=${=time-pos} --term-playing-msg=MPV_VERSION=${=mpv-version:}
INFO_VIDEO_WIDTH=${=width}
INFO_VIDEO_HEIGHT=${=height}
INFO_VIDEO_ASPECT=${=video-params/aspect}
INFO_VIDEO_FPS=${=container-fps:${=fps}}
INFO_VIDEO_FORMAT=${=video-format}
INFO_VIDEO_CODEC=${=video-codec}
INFO_AUDIO_FORMAT=${=audio-codec-name}
INFO_AUDIO_CODEC=${=audio-codec}
INFO_AUDIO_RATE=${=audio-params/samplerate}
INFO_AUDIO_NCH=${=audio-params/channel-count}
INFO_LENGTH=${=duration:${=length}}
INFO_DEMUXER=${=current-demuxer:${=demuxer}}
INFO_SEEKABLE=${=seekable}
INFO_TITLES=${=disc-titles}
INFO_CHAPTERS=${=chapters}
INFO_TRACKS_COUNT=${=track-list/count}
METADATA_TITLE=${metadata/by-key/title:}
METADATA_ARTIST=${metadata/by-key/artist:}
METADATA_ALBUM=${metadata/by-key/album:}
METADATA_GENRE=${metadata/by-key/genre:}
METADATA_DATE=${metadata/by-key/date:}
METADATA_TRACK=${metadata/by-key/track:}
METADATA_COPYRIGHT=${metadata/by-key/copyright:}
INFO_MEDIA_TITLE=${=media-title:}
INFO_STREAM_PATH=${stream-path}
 --audio-client-name=SMPlayer --term-status-msg=STATUS: ${=time-pos} / ${=duration:${=length:0}} P: ${=pause} B: ${=paused-for-cache} I: ${=core-idle} VB: ${=video-bitrate:0} AB: ${=audio-bitrate:0} /media/psw/WD3T/Youtube/Bring Back That Leroy Brown (Remastered 2011) (1080p_6fps_H264-128kbit_AAC).mp4

 (+) Video --vid=1 (*) (h264 1920x1080 6.000fps)
 (+) Audio --aid=1 (*) (aac 2ch 44100Hz)
File tags:
 Artist: Various Artists - Topic
 Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fkdnMrsvIjs
 Date: 2015
 Title: Bring Back That Leroy Brown (Remastered 2011)
Using hardware decoding (nvdec-copy).
AO: [pulse] 44100Hz stereo 2ch float
VO: [gpu] 1920x1080 nv12
INFO_VIDEO_DSIZE=1920x1080
MPV_VERSION=mpv 0.32.0
INFO_VIDEO_WIDTH=1920
INFO_VIDEO_HEIGHT=1080
INFO_VIDEO_ASPECT=1.777778
INFO_VIDEO_FPS=6.000000
INFO_VIDEO_FORMAT=h264
INFO_VIDEO_CODEC=h264 (H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10)
INFO_AUDIO_FORMAT=aac
INFO_AUDIO_CODEC=aac (AAC (Advanced Audio Coding))
INFO_AUDIO_RATE=44100
INFO_AUDIO_NCH=2
INFO_LENGTH=135.396000
INFO_DEMUXER=lavf
INFO_SEEKABLE=yes
INFO_TITLES=
INFO_CHAPTERS=0
INFO_TRACKS_COUNT=2
METADATA_TITLE=Bring Back That Leroy Brown (Remastered 2011)
METADATA_ARTIST=Various Artists - Topic
METADATA_ALBUM=
METADATA_GENRE=
METADATA_DATE=2015
METADATA_TRACK=
METADATA_COPYRIGHT=
INFO_MEDIA_TITLE=Bring Back That Leroy Brown (Remastered 2011)
INFO_STREAM_PATH=/media/psw/WD3T/Youtube/Bring Back That Leroy Brown (Remastered 2011) (1080p_6fps_H264-128kbit_AAC).mp4
INFO_TRACK_0: video 1 '' '' yes
INFO_TRACK_1: audio 1 '' '' yes
```

Is there any solution about this?